# Error: You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:maxLength="16"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtScreen"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnSeven"
                android:text="7" />
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnEight"
                android:text="8" />
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnNine"
                android:text="9"/>
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnDivide"
                android:text="/"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnFour"
                android:text="4"/>
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnFive"
                android:text="5" />
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnSix"
                android:text="6" />
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnMultiply"
                android:text="*" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnOne"
                android:text="1" />
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
                android:text="2" />
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnThree"
                android:text="3" />
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnSubtract"
                android:text="-" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnDot"
                android:text="." />
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnZero"
                android:text="0" />
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                android:text="C" />
            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                android:text="+" />

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:id="@+id/btnEqual"
                android:text="=" />
        </LinearLayout>





    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This was the question but i couldn't get the answer , kindly answer 
i have been facing this continuously , i found alot but could get help yet

Comment: mistake in writing detail SOrry to every one! Kindly answer

Comment: you are not setting button layout_height and width thats for u are getting error

Comment: The message tells you _exactly_ what is wrong.

Comment: add `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to all your buttons.

Comment: The error message  is self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

Every View must have width and hight so you have to assign values to android:layout_width and android:layout_hight attributes. so you have to declare width and hight to your buttons then it works...

Answer (score 0):

Please change accordingly...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtScreen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:maxLength="16"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtScreen"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSeven"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="7" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEight"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="8" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNine"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="9" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDivide"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="/" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFour"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFive"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSix"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="6" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMultiply"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="*" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnOne"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnThree"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSubtract"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="-" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDot"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="." />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnZero"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="C" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="+" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEqual"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:text="=" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self-explanatory. I think you need to read the basics of the Android layout management: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html